# Command not found

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

I downloaded the AWS CloudWatch command line api and I have also set the env_path variable that is `AWS_CLOUDWATCH_HOME=local/usr/CloudWatch`.
But when I run `mon-cmd`, I get command not found error in the console. I am working on ubuntu 10.04 server which is a EC2 instance.

It's been to couple of days I am struck with this problem, in spite of setting the path variables correctly I am facing this problem.

Kindly help me out

Comment: Can you find this command `mod-cmd` in your system somewhere? Use `locate` or `find` to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command not found usually means exactly that - that the operating system can't locate the command you are trying to execute. The operating system only looks in a select few folders for the application. This list of folders is defined by the PATH variable.

You can view your current PATH variable with:

```
echo $PATH
```

One possible output of this is:
    /usr/local/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/aws/bin:/root/bin

You will note, in the above output that I have my AWS API tools in `/opt/aws/bin`. Edit your PATH variable to include the location of the `mon-cmd` program. You can do so, either:
Temporarily (from bash prompt):

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/api-tools
```

Or permanently, by modifying (or appending) the PATH in your users' `.bash_profile`:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/api-tools
export $PATH
```

Be careful! Ensure you do not leave out the $PATH - this includes the existing PATH and only adds the new one - otherwise you will overwrite your existing PATH and no programs will work if they are not run with an absolute path.

You can verify that you have done so successfully by running (which should return the correct location)

```
whereis mon-cmd
```

(Sample output: `mon-cmd: /path/to/api-tools/mon-cmd`)

Alternatively, you can run the command directly from wherever it is located:

```
/path/to/api-tools/mod-cmd`
```

Answer (score 1):

Find the file with `find / -type f -name mon-cmd 2>/dev/null` then add the folder where the file is located to `$PATH` by running: `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to_mon-cmd/`